# App Script: get certain spreadsheet by name instead of active spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an App Scirpt that should work with certain Google Spreadsheet, let's say "database". I then embed this spreadsheet into other web documents, and schedule to run every minute.

From all the tutorials I learnt that I should use the `getActiveSheet()` function. But this deals with any opened active GSheet in the broswer.

How can I specify for the script to work exactly with the "database" Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout

- SpreadsheetApp.openById(id) or
- SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)

and see if that helps you ?

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))

If you want to use the name of the spreadsheet you'll have to use the DriveApp class:

- DriveApp.getFilesByName(name)

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String))

Comment: Amazing, thanks you! Found out, that I used a container, not standalone, script. I tried to use your answer with a custom function, but this works only in contained scripts for particular spreadsheets. So I dropped the custom function in favor setValues. Now I can specify any spreadsheet by ID in my standalone script.